# bad words filter without bad words

Tags: nlp, bloom-filter

I need a "bad words" filter without the bad words, because I don't want to have a list of bad words on my system. I'm thinking that the easiest way to do this is with a Bloom Filter used to store the SHA1 from a set of bad words. Is there any other approach that I should consider?

Comment: I feel an urge to write `this is a fxxxing good idea` :-)

Comment: Why not do both with and without bad words? `pip install expletives` (Shameless plug: https://github.com/alvations/expletives)

Comment: Huh? what do you mean, with and without bad words? A list of all good words?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Bloom filter for this works well. For probability of false positives, you should use a relatively low value, for example p = 0.000001 (0.0001% false positives).

SHA-1: For most uses, it doesn't need to be SHA-1. Calculating the SHA-1 hash is relatively slow, specially if you have a lot of content to hash. (Remember you will have to hash each word separately.) Instead, you could use Murmur hash (for example). That way, hashing is much faster. If you are concerned about somebody on purpose trying to get hash collisions (why would someone do that I can't say), then the seed should be kept secret. And maybe use something a bit stronger like SipHash (as Murmur hash isn't designed for security).